# Is there any way to optimize a complex math query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, math, optimization

I've been researching this forever and I am starting to think I can't make this any more efficient, but I wanted to ask if anyone had any tips.

I'm running a query on millions of records to find all the x,y,z coordinates (these are stars) along a linear column from system a to system b with a given radius. I'm running through PHP with a lot of other work being done on the result set. I get results from the script in about 16 seconds. The query delay is about 7 of those 16 seconds.

The basic query logic is:

```
SELECT name, coordinates, and distance from end point
FROM stars
WHERE all stars are in a column of given radius between start and end points
ORDER BY distance from end point DESC
```

The where clause requires two separate calculations, they are this:

Where calculation 1:

```
Calculate if the stars are within the space of the column using constants and x,y,z
```

Where calculation 2:

```
Limit the column radius to a given figure.
(This where clause also performs similar calculations with the same constants and x,y,z.)
```

The math formulas in the where clauses can't really be changed, they are the formula needed for columnar calculation in 3D space.

The order by at the end of the query is absolutely necessary because the result set is too large for my script to hold in memory. I have to work with it in the proper order in the script.

The query is easiest to read as defined prior to variable substitution:

```
SELECT
    name,
    x,
    y,
    z,
    SQRT(
        pow(`x`-" . $bx . ",2)+
        pow(`y`-" . $by . ",2)+
        pow(`z`-" . $bz . ",2)
    ) d
FROM
    stars
WHERE
    (((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) between 0 and 1
AND
    SQRT(((($ax + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cx))-`x`)*(($ax + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cx))-`x`))+((($ay + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cy))-`y`)*(($ay + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cy))-`y`))+((($az + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cz))-`z`)*(($az + ((((`x`*$cx+`y`*$cy+`z`*$cz)-($constant_1))/($constant_2)) * $cz))-`z`)))
        <=$radius
ORDER BY
    SQRT(
        pow(`x`-" . $bx . ",2)+
        pow(`y`-" . $by . ",2)+
        pow(`z`-" . $bz . ",2)
    ) DESC
```

The final query run on the database looks like this: (For simplicity, I'm using sample data where a lot of the constants are 0.)

```
SELECT
    name, 
    x, 
    y, 
    z, 
    SQRT( pow(`x`-25.21875,2)+ pow(`y`--20.90625,2)+ pow(`z`-25899.96875,2) ) d
FROM
    stars
WHERE
    (((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) 
    between 0 and 1
AND
    SQRT((((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * 25.21875))-`x`)*((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * 25.21875))-`x`))+(((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * -20.90625))-`y`)*((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * -20.90625))-`y`))+(((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * 25899.96875))-`z`)*((0 + ((((`x`*25.21875+`y`*-20.90625+`z`*25899.96875)-(0))/(670809454.308)) * 25899.96875))-`z`)))
    <=600
ORDER BY
    SQRT( pow(`x`-25.21875,2)+ pow(`y`--20.90625,2)+ pow(`z`-25899.96875,2) ) DESC
```

My table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stars` (
    `localkey` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `x` double NOT NULL,
    `y` double NOT NULL,
    `z` double NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`localkey`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `x` (`x`),
KEY `y` (`y`),
KEY `z` (`z`),
KEY `xyz` (`x`,`y`,`z`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The explain for the query results indicates no index usage and an extra of:

```
extra: Using where; Using filesort;
```

What I've tried so far:

- Adjusting various data types to optimize memory usage and indexing (Even though my math makes it unlikely indexes will ever be used)
- Using a PHP loop and multiple smaller queries instead of this one huge one (It took longer with multiple queries.)
- Copying to a memory table before running query (Table is too large to fit in memory)
- Copying only part of the table (localkey, x, y, z) to memory. (It fit, but left so little of max_heap_size for other processes it wasn't worth it.)

Are there other options I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what starts data-set is this? Is this some artificial dataset you are working with , or is this a open source dataset available. Would be cool if you can point me to it. thanks!

Comment: @Shaunak Sorry for the delay in response. I was replying via phone on the other comments and couldn't easily answer. There are multiple resources for star data sets: 

http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/

But I'm actually making this as a tool to help my other hobby, which is playing space sims. The data set I am using is based on Simbad I believe, but the game makers have tweaked some names for story purposes. My data set is from here:

https://www.edsm.net/nightly-dumps

Edits: Accidentally submitted without URLS

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that only a smaller subset of your records will match, you can reduce the math load by doing a basic "rectangular" filtering first. e.g. there's no point in performing a full cartesian distance for EVERY record in the table, only to throw away most of them.

A simple "box" boundary check is just a simple subtraction and comparison:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ...
    WHERE (
        (abs($x_coord - x_coordinate) <= $max_distance)
     OR (abs($y_coord - y_coordinate) <= $max_distance)
    )
) AS square_filter
WHERE ... full calculation here
```

Of cousre, you're doing 3d positions, so it's a bit more complicated, but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you. Since this is just a hobby, I only really have a little time each week to work on it. But this sounds like an excellent way to reduce the set. May help a ton. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent suggestion of fast pre-filtering that Marc B suggested above, when you do your second pass, you might save a little computing in the distance formula in two ways:

1) use (x-k) * (x-k) instead of calling pow(x-k, ...)

2) skip the square root and calculate distance squared.  You would then compare to square of the distance that you need, which only needs to be calculated once.

Comment: Both excellent suggestions. I can re-write the query easily to avoid pow. And I think using the square and then having php do the square root only when needed would be a huge impact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Along with the two great mathematical optimizations suggested, the biggest jump in improving the speed would be form **minimizing any computation and reducing your search space**. That means Spatial Indexing.

I am not an expert in MySQL, but idea is you pre-generate spatial indexes in 3D space so your search space is dramatically reduced.

To be more precise, with a full table scan, your complexity becomes *O(n^2)*. The time required to search increases with the size of table, and how far down the table you search. However with tree based spatial index it can be reduced to *O(n log n)*

Think about this dividing the space into fixed size cubes (and cubes within cubes). Not unlike how google map arranges tiles. Now with the indexing, you have a "wormhole" to each cube, based on the initial coordinates, as you can calculate the cube you can find a star in with **O(n)** time. Then all you have to do is run search in this cube.

Here's some reference in [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) on spatial indexes.

I faced a similar problem dealing with LiDAR data in two coordinates few years back. Here's the link to my question and answers that may help you get some ideas:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/optimize-nearest-neighbor-query-on-70-million-point-cloud-on-sql-server-2008

Comment: Thanks. I'll look it up and see how I can do. I should be able to come up with a way of identifying cubes that then align with the result set I need. May be a great increase. I'll have to test it and see.

Answer (score 0):

The bounding-box approach might even use an index on *one* of the dimensions.  But not if written the way Marc suggests.  Instead:

```
`x` BETWEEN $x - $dist AND $x + $dist
```

The general principle is that you should not hide an indexed variable in a function.  `ABS` in this example.

Also...

```
ORDER BY d -- this will avoid recomputing the SQRT
```

Does double minus in `pow(y--20.90625,2)` really work?  To fix it, swap them:

```
pow(-20.90625 - `y`,2)
```

It is messier to set up, but multiply *might* be faster than POW:

```
(-20.90625 - `y`) * (-20.90625 - `y`)
```

Comment: Yea, the double minus seems to work. (Not sure if it decreases efficiency). But changing the order and multiplying has a good chance of being an improvement.